# Where can we see stats of votes on comments?

Tags: support, feature-request, comments

I note that we can follow the up-/downvotes on our questions and answers, but there is not a convenient place to find stats on the upvotes on our comments on questions and answers.  Is this one of the advanced privileges earned after attaining >10,000 reputation or some other qualifying event?

Answer (score 7):

There's very little that you can say about comments. This is by design: comments are explicitly relegated to a second-class, transient role, and SE has been very clear that anything that would increase their importance (thereby turning SE into a discussion-board type of forum, at the detriment of the straightforward readability of the Q&A format) will not be taken up.

[This Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/701024/all-a-users-comments) can find all your comments, including their score, but that's about all the information available. There is no rep-earnable site privilege that enables any additional visibility into the comment statistics.

Comment: Ah okay, I wasn't sure whether this was tracked or known.  I noticed that some comments had lots of upvotes and it made me curious if any of my comments made it to the "red color" stage or not.

Comment: @honeste_vivere You get what's in the linked query but no more than that.

Comment: I was not aware of this Data Explorer part of SE, nice.  I found a pre-made query for this specific task at:  [https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution).

Comment: @honeste_vivere Yeah; note also that the column headers on the output can be used to re-sort on different criteria. Also, if you're going to muck around with SEDE, [the database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) are very useful.

Comment: Ah that sounds interesting, but I better not...  I am already overly distracted by my own programming.  If I start digging into this, I will lose several days ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is another way in which the decision to have comments be second class citizens shows in the interface: there is no feature for tracking such things.

You can construct a query in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to learn about the situation up to the most recent capture.